# array size different in simulator then on iphone

Tags: ios, arrays

I have the following code:

```
    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i = 1; i <= 32; i++) {
        //NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"marker_%i.png", i];
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"wave%i.png", i];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:str];
        if(img != nil) {
            [imageArray addObject:img];
        }

    }
    NSLog(@"imageArray count %i",[imageArray count]);

    NSMutableArray *reverseArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:imageArray];
    [[reverseArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
    [imageArray addObjectsFromArray:reverseArray];

    NSLog(@"imageArray count %i",[imageArray count]);
```

If i run it on the iphone i get:

`2013-05-12 15:21:08.539 RouteApp[5673:907] imageArray count 23`

`2013-05-12 15:21:08.545 RouteApp[5673:907] imageArray count 46`

while if i run in the simulator i get 32 and 64 like i expect.
(like if the numbers are switched)

What can cause this?

Comment: Note that `[[reverseArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects]` does not have any effect since you discard the return value.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I get the impression you're creating an array of images for an animation. If so, note that you're going to repeat the middle image, a la `wave30.png` `wave31.png` `wave32.png` `wave32.png` `wave31.png` `wave30.png`, with the doubled 32. If so then you might want to only count up to 31 and add 32 manually between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like some of the images are missing on the iPhone, so this line

```
if(img != nil) {
    [imageArray addObject:img];
}
```

filters them out. Change this line as follows to see which images are not present:

```
if(img != nil) {
    [imageArray addObject:img];
} else {
    NSLog("Image 'wave%i.png' is missing", i);
}
```

Comment: ah good call. some images are named 01, 02 etc. So i have to format them.

Comment: @clankill3r You could also change `%i` to `%02i`, and keep image names the same.

Answer (score 0):

Filenames on the device are case-sensitive, but are not on the simulator. Some of your image names are likely slightly different from the format you're expecting.

The most common way this happens is something like `wave01.png` vs. `wave01.PNG`.

Otherwise it's probably something like `wave01.png` vs. `Wave01.png`, etc.